# Asp.net TagHelper to add a class depending on an expression (inspired by Angular)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am thinking about to create an tagHelper-attribute in the way of Angular.
In Angular I can do following:

```
<div [class.extra-sparkle]="isDelightful"></div>
```

This binds an css-class `extra-sparkle` depending on the bool-expression `isDelightful` to the div-tag.

I was thinking about to to the same in asp.net core mvc.

**1. Idea**

My first thought was to do it like this, but in this way the attribute-part 'myClass' has to be defined in a kind of wildcard attribute like 'myPrefix-*'.
But so far i saw there is no wildcard-option.

```
<div myPrefix-myClass="(expression)"></div>
```

**2. Idea**

My second idea was to use an attribute type of Func-Delegate.

```
<div myPrefix-class-if="("myClass", Model)=> Model.x == true"></div>
```

But in this case I'm struggeling with the razor-syntax and I also don't know,
whether it's possible to use a Func-Delegate as an property within a taghelper.

Does anybody know a possible solution or have an idea?

Comment: Please read the [editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I think you are trying to get code to run in the tag helper itself and that is not how tag helpers work. They simply execute a method inside the tag helper class.